# DTD validation from JaxB classes

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling, dtd

I had to create some java classes for XML generation starting from a DTD file.

I used jxc utility:

```
xjc -dtd -d generatedsrc -p com.examples log4j.dtd
```

I could generate the xml but it is refused from the receiver and I have no other information but this DTD. How can I validate a DTD against a XML?
For example in the DTD can be define a mandatory field that I did not set in my object before marshalling, how can I find what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some examples for validating DTD against xml. I will paste here one for convenience but also the link on the end.

For a given xml with dtd included, invalid_dtd.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- invalid_dtd.xml
 - Copyright (c) 2002-2014 HerongYang.com, All Rights Reserved.
-->
<!DOCTYPE dictionary [
 <!ELEMENT dictionary (note, word+)>
 <!ELEMENT note ANY>
 <!ELEMENT word (update?, name, definition+, usage*)>
 <!ELEMENT update EMPTY>
 <!ATTLIST update 
  date CDATA #REQUIRED 
  editor CDATA #IMPLIED
 >
 <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
 <!ATTLIST name is_acronym (true | false) "false">
 <!ELEMENT definition (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT usage (#PCDATA | i)*>
 <!ELEMENT i (#PCDATA)>
 <!ENTITY herong "Dr. Herong Yang">
]>
<dictionary>
 <note>Copyright (c) 2014 by &herong;</note>
 <word>
  <name is_acronym="true" language="EN">POP</name>
  <definition>Post Office Protocol</definition>
  <definition>Point Of Purchase</definition>
 </word>
 <word>
  <update date="2014-12-23"/> 
  <name is_acronym="yes">XML</name>
  <definition>eXtensible Markup Language</definition>
  <note>XML comes from SGML</note>
 </word>
 <word>
  <update editor="Herong Yang"/> 
  <name>markup</name>
  <definition>The amount added to the cost price to calculate 
the selling price - <i>Webster</i></definition>
 </word>
</dictionary>
```

A simple class to run some checks:

```
public class DOMValidator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File x = new File("invalid_dtd.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(true);
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            ErrorHandler h = new MyErrorHandler();
            documentBuilder.setErrorHandler(h);
            documentBuilder.parse(x);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
    private static class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
        public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("Warning: ");
            printInfo(e);
        }
        public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("Error: ");
            printInfo(e);
        }
        public void fatalError(SAXParseException e)
                throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("Fattal error: ");
            printInfo(e);
        }
        private void printInfo(SAXParseException e) {
            System.out.println("   Public ID: "+e.getPublicId());
            System.out.println("   System ID: "+e.getSystemId());
            System.out.println("   Line number: "+e.getLineNumber());
            System.out.println("   Column number: "+e.getColumnNumber());
            System.out.println("   Message: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Is it something you could use maybe?

Original source: http://www.herongyang.com/XML/DTD-Validation-of-XML-with-DTD-Using-DOM.html

Comment: Yes maybe I will try it thanks. So far I found only a generic command tool but it just give me "error" without where it was. Thanks

Comment: @Tobia if you share your xml, dtd I could help and be more specific

Comment: I could use this validation, I found my error thanks